# Multiple fetch requests with each mapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from backend called 'activity' .. and each activity has a number of images that needs another fetch request .. so i tried to fetch the activities in the parent component and mapping each activity to create a child component called Activity and sending the activity as props to the child component as below

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchActivities = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_BACKEND_ACTIVITIES , {
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`
        }
      })
      const json = await response.json()

      if (response.ok) {
        setIsLoading(true)
        dispatch({type:'SET_ACTIVITIES', payload: json})
      }
    }
    user && fetchActivities()
  }, [dispatch, user])

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <div>
          {
            activities && activities.map((activity) => (
              <Activity key={activity._id} activity={activity} />
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
```

then created the child component (Activity) to fetch the images and fetch all images assigned to this activity in a url with the activity id as below

```
const Activity= ({ activity }) => {
    // const { activityImgs, dispatch } = useActivityImgContext()
    const { user } = useAuthContext()

    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetching Images for each activity ----------------------
        const fetchActivityImgs = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_BACKEND_ACTIVITIES + activity._id, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`
                }
            })
            const json = await response.json()
            if (response.ok) {
                dispatch({type:'SET_ACTIVITY_IMGS', payload: json})
            }
        }
        fetchActivityImgs()
        //---------------------------------------------------------
    }, [dispatch, activity])

  return (
    <Container>
        <Wrapper>
            <DataContainer style={{flexDirection: activity.flexDirection}}>
                <ActivityEdit style={{direction:activity.flexDirection=='row'? 'rtl' : 'ltr'}}>
                    <ActivityTitle>
                        {activity.activityTitle}
                    </ActivityTitle>
                    <ActivityDesc>
                        {activity.activityDescription}
                    </ActivityDesc>
                </ActivityEdit>
                <ImgsContainer>
                    {!activityImgs && (
                            <h1>No Images</h1>
                    )}
                    <ActivityCarousel>
                        {
                            activityImgs && activityImgs.map((activityImg)=>{
                                if (activityImg.activity_id === activity._id) {
                                    return (
                                        <img key={activityImg._id} src={activityImg.imageUrl} className='img-fluid' />
                                    )
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    </ActivityCarousel>
                </ImgsContainer>
            </DataContainer>
        </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Activity;
```

I expected to get the images assigned to each activity in it's component

but it only gets one of the activities's images and doesn't get the others